# gradient alternative to color the button

Tags: android, button

I have a shape in android button, i wanted it colored two colors. but not gradient. just the colors as is , how can it be done? below is my drawable. I dont want it gradient, just two colors as is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#e574bd"
        android:startColor="#874dbc"
        android:type="linear" />
    <corners
        android:radius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

Edit: I attached image how I want it to look like[image]

```
 <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/registration"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/default_margin"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/default_margin"
                    android:background="@drawable/abovexml"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/sadad2"
                        android:src="@+id/theimagewithoutwordingchangepassword"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/loginText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/changepass"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/buttonSize"></TextView>
                </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: if you can provide sample image of what you want and what your current output looks like, it helps to identify more.

Comment: Can you post expected design ?

Comment: done.  You can help now, thank you

Comment: so basically i am putting the image in relative layout, however on the sides i am coloring since it is cornered. and the colors are not working with the image.

Comment: You can directly set textview background. `android:background="@drawable/background_drawable"`

Comment: the problem is that the background image i have is rectangle, i want it cornered.

Comment: okey i got solution, it was simply using cardview with cornered radius. and put image inside that cardview. thank you